# Singleton not working

Tags: singleton, c#-3.0

I have written a singleton code and I believe it should not be working.It may feel it is low level question but it will help me in understanding.
Can anyone check and appolgy if it is not worth posting here.

It is creating two instance.Why??

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SingletonTest
{


public sealed class Test
{
    private static readonly Test instance = new Test();


    static Test()
    {
    }

    private Test()
    {
    }

    public static Test Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}


class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {



        var singletonSampleClass = Test.Instance;
        singletonSampleClass.Message = "Hello";
        Console.WriteLine("Singleton class usage: " + singletonSampleClass.Message);


        var singletonSampleClass2 = Test.Instance;
        singletonSampleClass2.Message = "Hello1";
        Console.WriteLine("Singleton class usage: " + singletonSampleClass2.Message);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

Thanks
in advance.

Comment: You haven't said what's *actually* happening vs what you *expected* to happen. You say "I believe it should not be working" - what do you mean by "working" and why do you think it shouldn't behave that way? We can't answer the question in its current form.

Comment: Sir,I mean..why I am able to create two instance in this.Is it not a proper singleton.?

Comment: is it because I have not used "new" and reference is created but not instance?

Comment: Thanks,i was stupid .was creating refernce and taking that as an  object .Thanks a lot.Sorry for taking your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var singletonSampleClass = Test.Instance; //First reference
singletonSampleClass.Message = "First Change";
Console.WriteLine("Singleton class usage: " + singletonSampleClass.Message);
// Expected to be "Singleton class usage: First Change"

var singletonSampleClass2 = Test.Instance; //Second reference
Console.WriteLine("Singleton class usage: " + singletonSampleClass2.Message);
// Expected to be "Singleton class usage: First Change" aka you have the same instance

singletonSampleClass2.Message = "Second Change";
Console.WriteLine("Singleton class usage: " + singletonSampleClass.Message); //use the first reference
// Expected to be "Singleton class usage: Second Change" even though you changed the instance with the second reference
Console.Read();
```

and you will find out that you have only 1 instance ... you had 2 references in your example but still only 1 instance

Comment: Thanks,i was stupid .was creating refernce and taking that as an  object .Thanks a lot.

Comment: objects are stored on the heap. you can have as many references as you want to a single object. they point only to the same address.